# Cannot connect with wireless network on Ubuntu Server 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, wifi, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to configure one of our servers for our wireless network. I just installed Ubuntu Server 14.04, and I'm using a USB wireless adaptor. I've run `lsusb` and I can see the device, I've also run `sudo iwlist wlan0 scan` (after running `sudo ifconfig wlan0 up` to start the wireless interface) and I can see our network I want to connect listed there. However, with my configuration I cannot get a connection (with static or DHCP). I'm just trying initially with a DHCP IP as it seems simpler, then I'd like to configure a static IP. It seems it's not even connecting with the gateway:

```
ping 192.168.11.1
connect: Network is unreachable
```

If I do this on a configured laptop which is connecting, it pongs back with bytes received etc (the latop doesn't seem to have it's wlan0 configuration in the same files though). Is there anything at this stage I can run to perhaps asses where the fault might be? It's my first time to try to configure a wireless connection manually so not really sure what tools to diagnose with next.

Anyway, below is my /etc/network/interfaces for the new server:

```
auto lo
    2 iface lo inet loopback

auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
    wpa-ssid tobunerima
    wpa-psk local
```

(this is the password in plain text)

UPDATE 1

```
$ sudo ip ad
ip link show

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:1d:09:14:8f:52 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether cc:e1:d5:3f:a5:bd brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

When I run `sudo ip ro` there is nothing:

```
$ sudo ip ro
$
```

UPDATE 2

Here is the output of `sudo iwconfig wlan0`

```
wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off
```

UPDATE 3

Output of `sudo ifup wlan0`:

```
wpa_supplicant: WARNING: plaintext or ascii WPA key has 3 characters,
wpa_supplicant: it must have between 8 and 63 to be valid.
wpa_supplicant: If the WPA key is a 256-bit hexadecimal key, it must have
wpa_supplicant: exactly 64 characters.
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client V3.1.3

Copyright 2004-2009 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/

Listening on LPF/wlan0/00:1d:e0:a6:30:2f
Sending on LPF/wlan0/00:1d:e0:a6:30:2f
Sending on Socket/fallback
DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3
DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 6
DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 10
DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 20
DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 15
DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 7
.
.
.
No DHCPOFFERS received
No working leases in persistent database - sleeping.
```

Comment: "Network is unreachable" means a routing-level problem.  If you obtained a DHCP lease, your DHCP server is probably misconfigured; if you configured the interface statically on the command line, you probably did it wrong -- perhaps typo'd something.  The output of `ip ad` and `ip ro` will probably show us what you've done wrong.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I've updated my post with outputs from those commands.

Comment: "When I run `sudo ip ro` there is nothing".  Therein lies the immediate cause of your problem.  You didn't get a DHCP lease (no IP address), and it doesn't even look like the system *tried* (link state is `DOWN`).  On the other hand, something has tried to bring the link up (admin link state is `UP`).  Time to go digging into `dmesg`, to work out why your wireless isn't connecting.  sudo iwconfig wlan0` might be useful to see, too.

Comment: Hi, I'm updated my post with those outputs (UPDATE 2). I wasn't sure what was relevant in dmesg, sorry about the huge dump of text :)

Comment: Hmm, no smoking gun in there, but it does confirm my suspicion that the wifi isn't getting a link.  At this point, by far the most likely issue is an incorrect SSID/password.

Comment: No probs, thanks for taking the time. I tried `sudo iwconfig wlan0 essid tobunerima key s:local` which gives no errors, but if I misspell the password I get `Error for wireless request "Set Encode" (8B2A) : SET failed on device wlan0 ; Invalid argument.`. Also is there a CLI command to manually connect? I thought `sudo ifconfig wlan0 up` (iwconfig shows error for `up` command) but this doesn't work on my laptop either, I only know to click the connection icon and the wireless connection is brought back up. Maybe in Ubuntu Server I just need to ensure such a command is run?

Comment: You haven't run `ifup wlan0`?  That's the canonical command to configure an interface.  If it says, "interface is already configured", run `ifdown wlan0` and then `ifup wlan0`.

Comment: No, sorry. I'm kinda doing this for the first time on Ubuntu Server. Anyway, I tried those commands (yes, I had to run `ifdown` first). Would appear to be struggling to lease an IP. It runs for a long time but continually attempts "DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67..." then fails. See my UPDATE 3 in my post. I get errors regarding the length of the password, I can't change that though is it's a shared router I don't have control over. Also, should the password be stored in /etc/network/interfaces as plain text?

Comment: The message makes it clear that either your password or some other security setting is wrong. Exactly what is the story with this mystery router?

Comment: The password in `/etc/network/interfaces` shouldn't be encrypted in any way, if that's what you mean.  If your router requires a password of a certain length, that sounds like WEP, which (a) is terribad, and (b) is configured differently to WPA PSK.

Comment: The router is in shared accommodation and the landlord manages that :) I hoped that perhaps I could just copy the configuration from my laptop which connects to the same wifi network. However, in it's `/etc/network/interfaces` it only has the lo loopback interface. If I `grep -r wlan0 /etc/` then I can only see a result for that in `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules`. I can't see anywhere else where wlan0 is configured but when I run 'iwconfig wlan0' I see the ESSID it's connected to and the Access Point has an address. On the server, ESSID is set but Access Point is "Not-Associated".